# Unity3d "Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to `bool'"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () 
{
    if (transform.Translate((Input.acceleration.x), 0, 0)) 
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector2.right);
    }
}
```

I am using the accelerator for a Android App and doesn't seem to like it. I can change it to work for KeyDown but it wont work with the accelerator.

Error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type "void" to "bool"

Comment: Does `transform.Translate` method actually return `bool` value?

Comment: The Method signature is `void Update()`. Therefore it's not meant to return anything. Change it to ` bool Update()` if you want a boolean returned.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane There is no `return` in the `Update` method.  It's more likely that `Translate` is `void` as Dovydas points out.

Comment: @juharr apologies, I read it backwards. Not so simple as it seems :)

Comment: think it throught - if translate would return a boolean, what would it mean? that the translation was successful? but there is nothing hindering you from translating the object ever (collisions are seperate, a feature of colliders).

Comment: Don't what you're trying to check with your if statement logic, it doesn't seem to make any sense to me, but [Translate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) returns void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html:

transform.Translate does not return a boolean; its return type is void. Therefore you cannot use an if statement to evaluate whether or not it was successful.

If you want to check to see if the translate happened correctly you would need to check the side effects from calling transform.Translate. In other words see what has changed on the transform and see if it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the if statement, as Translate returns nothing. Just leave the AddForce line